# Boundary Conditions for a System of Multiple Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matlab, python

I'm currently confused about how to solve this two-dimensional coupled PDE. I'm currently using Matlab to solve it using the $pdepe$ function, but I don't have related initial and boundary conditions for the $w$ function shown in the third equation. If there's a way to solve this manually or with another program, instructions would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

$$
\ \\
Equations \\
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -w \ \cdot \ u \ + \ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = -w \ \cdot \ u \ + \ \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = -w \ \cdot \ (u \ + \ v)\\
\ \\
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
$$

$$
Boundary \ \ Conditions \\
\rule{6cm}{0.4pt}
$$
$$
u(x,0) = u_0 \\
v(x,0) = 0 \\
w(0,t) = w_0 \\
\rule{6cm}{0.4pt}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(0,t) = 0 \\ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_{max},t) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x_{max},t) = 0 \\
\ \\
\rule{6cm}{0.4pt}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if pdepe is suitable to solve this system because pdepe was designed to solve parabolic-elliptic PDEs and your third equation is hyperbolic.

You can check this discussion: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/402158-system-of-pdes-which-is-tricky-for-pdepe

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I've been looking for how to discretize the third equation. Since there are no second-order partials involved, I'm wondering how to get started with solving for it.